# Dictionary list populating the same data 255 times

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some trouble trying to yield my dictionary in every run of my "for" loop. I have a csv file that I got from ICANN and want to populate the dictionary with the data and yield each unique dictionary but after doing so and print the resulting list, I have the same dictionary 255 times. The strange thing is if I specifically print `ip_data["prefix"]` it will print from 000 - 255.

```
import csv
import re


def populate_dictionary():
    line_count = 0
    ip_data = {"prefix": "", "designation": "", "status": ""}
    ip_data_list = []

    with open("ipv4-address-space.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        else:
            ip_data["prefix"]      = row[0]
            ip_data["designation"] = row[1]
            ip_data["status"]      = row[5]
            line_count += 1
            yield ip_data


ip_dictionary_list = populate_dictionary()
print(*ip_dictionary_list)
```

Even if I return a list after the looping rather than yield a dictionary, I have exactly the same issue when printing the list.

Output:

```
{'prefix': '255/8', 'designation': 'Future use', 'status': 'RESERVED'}
{'prefix': '255/8', 'designation': 'Future use', 'status': 'RESERVED'}
{'prefix': '255/8', 'designation': 'Future use', 'status': 'RESERVED'}
{'prefix': '255/8', 'designation': 'Future use', 'status': 'RESERVED'}
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the code a little easier for you to debug. Do take a look and let me know if it works.

```
import csv
import re

def populate_dictionary():

    with open("ipv4-address-space.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

    for row in csv_reader:
            yield {"prefix": row[0], "designation": row[1], "status": row[5]}

ip_dictionary_list = populate_dictionary()
print(*ip_dictionary_list)
```

Also, try adding the newline attribute in the open function where you first open the CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for that. I used your line that yields the data and added it to my else statement. And it works fine. Cheers.

Comment: Happy to help! Do remember to remove any unused variables from the code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make a new ip_data everytime you come inside the loop. Otherwise you just keep using the same object.

```
        else:
            ip_data = {}
            ip_data["prefix"]      = row[0]
            ip_data["designation"] = row[1]
            ip_data["status"]      = row[5]
            line_count += 1
            yield ip_data
```

Comment: Well, that object does (is supposed to) get overwritten in every iteration (each row). So, I don't suppose that's a problem.

Comment: Since he is pasting the ref in the list, it does not happen unless  you get a new instance of dict. He keeps modifying the same dict and putting it again and again. And at the end he gets the result of last operation.